# Python web application with google maps API & my SQL

Tags: python, mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, web-applications

I'm creating a web page (in Python) of hiking trails in MA. I want to be able to click on the name of a trail, and have my web page display a google map of the location. In my database, I have 2 columns, for latitude and longitude. I'm pretty new to Python, and don't really know how to go about this. Here is the code that I've written:

```
def getMap():
"""
This is a middleware function which returns
latitude and longitude coordinates
from our database.
"""

# connect to db
conn, cursor = getConnectionAndCursor()

# prepare SQL
sql = """
SELECT lat
AND lng
FROM hiking
WHERE name = %s
"""
parameters=(name,)
# run the SQL
cursor.execute(sql, name)

# fetch the results
data = cursor.fetchall()

# clean up
cursor.close()
conn.close()

return data

def showMap(lat,lng):
"""
Presentation layer function to display a Google map.
"""
 ## create an HTML table for output:
print"""
<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
</script>

<script>
function initialize() {
var mapProp = {
center:new google.maps.LatLng(%s,%s),
zoom:15,
mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
""" % (lat, lng)

if __name__ == "__main__":

# get form field data
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
debugFormData(form)

doHTMLHead("MassHike: A database of popular Massachusetts trails")
if 'name' in form:

    name=form['name'].value
    mapdata = getMap()
    showMap()
else:

    data = getAllHikes()
    showAllHikes(data)


doHTMLTail()
```

I asked a teaching assistant for help on this today, and she had no clue how to go about this. My web page is giving me an error saying ': showMap() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)', so I'm doing something very wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: update: didn't notice that showMap function was empty. Put in parameters, and now i get this error '<type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'lat' is not defined'

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the arguments when you call the function. Currently you are just calling showMap(). Your function `def showMap(lat,lng)` declares two required arguments; lat & lng. You must provide theses when calling it.

I do not see where you are declaring the latitude and longitude. You need to get these numbers somewhere and put them into the function.

Example call w/ literals:
`showMap('123','999')`

Example call w/ vars:  
`varLat = 40.44062479999999` 
`varLng = -79.99588640000002` 
`showMap(varLat,varLng)`